# Texture repeats and overlaps in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am creating a texture from svg files, mapping it on planes and returning the bitmap mesh to a callback. Problem is that first texture works fine but when I apply the second texture the plane has both first and second texture and this continues.

EDIT : What is really surprising is that console.log(mesh.material.map.image.src) is
showing the correct image for each icon(no overlap). Other than that each three.js group has just 2 children one for the overlay image and other for the blue background.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var cameraWidth = window.innerWidth;
var cameraHeight = window.innerHeight;
var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(cameraWidth / -2, cameraWidth / 2, cameraHeight / 2, cameraHeight / -2, 0, 10000);

var webGLRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
webGLRenderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0x555555, 1.0));
webGLRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

camera.position.x = 0;
camera.position.y = 0;
camera.position.z = 100;
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
scene.add(ambientLight);


var TURTLEPALETTEICON = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="55" height="55"> <path d="m 27.567493,45.252146 c -0.46948,0 -0.933016,-0.02903 -1.389761,-0.08296 l 1.178368,1.948634 1.161389,-1.918769 c -0.314968,0.02489 -0.629086,0.05309 -0.949996,0.05309 z" style="fill:none;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:1.20000005;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none" /> <path d="m 38.317981,14.929279 c -1.837168,0 -3.360217,1.289964 -3.68707,2.992219 1.578232,1.115757 2.934884,2.584076 3.968928,4.320343 1.939893,-0.142684 3.475677,-1.709721 3.475677,-3.641764 0,-2.027442 -1.682656,-3.670798 -3.757535,-3.670798 z" style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:2.29999995;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none" /> <path d="m 38.787461,38.290488 c -1.039138,1.851575 -2.42805,3.426908 -4.072502,4.609029 0.442312,1.546298 1.878767,2.686942 3.603022,2.686942 2.07403,0 3.757535,-1.642527 3.757535,-3.669969 0,-1.870656 -1.437304,-3.397874 -3.288055,-3.626002 z" style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:2.29999995;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none" /> <path d="m 16.340734,38.277215 c -1.912727,0.170889 -3.41625,1.724653 -3.41625,3.639275 0,2.026612 1.680958,3.669969 3.755837,3.669969 1.752271,0 3.212497,-1.177974 3.626793,-2.764091 -1.598607,-1.174655 -2.950165,-2.728419 -3.96638,-4.545153 z" style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:2.29999995;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none" /> <path d="m 20.375881,18.007772 c -0.291196,-1.744563 -1.828678,-3.078493 -3.69556,-3.078493 -2.074879,0 -3.755837,1.643356 -3.755837,3.669968 0,1.97601 1.601155,3.575399 3.603872,3.655037 1.006876,-1.694789 2.319381,-3.139051 3.847525,-4.246512 z" style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:2.29999995;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none" /> <path d="m 27.567493,15.62362 c 1.619832,0 3.164955,0.340948 4.599711,0.935742 0.629086,-0.892605 1.000085,-1.971862 1.000085,-3.138221 0,-3.058584 -2.537567,-5.5389654 -5.668563,-5.5389654 -3.130146,0 -5.667713,2.4803814 -5.667713,5.5389654 0,1.18461 0.383734,2.280457 1.032345,3.180529 1.463622,-0.62134 3.04525,-0.97805 4.704135,-0.97805 z" style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:2.29999995;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none" /> <g transform="matrix(0.8489685,0,0,0.82955893,4.2234061,5.2018707)" style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:1.42992032;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"> <path d="m 43.102,30.421 c 0,4.7344 -1.6452,9.2798 -4.5706,12.6275 -2.9254,3.3478 -6.8973,5.2305 -11.0344,5.2305 -4.1371,0 -8.109,-1.8827 -11.0344,-5.2305 -2.9254,-3.3477 -4.5706,-7.8931 -4.5706,-12.6275 0,-9.7966 7.0444,-17.858 15.605,-17.858 8.5606,0 15.605,8.0614 15.605,17.858 z" style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:1.42992032;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none" /> </g> <g transform="matrix(0.8489685,0,0,0.82955893,4.2234061,5.2018707)" style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"> <path d="m 25.875,33.75 -1.542,-4.625 3.164,-2.587 3.615,2.626 -1.487,4.669 z" style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" /> <path d="m 27.501,41.551 c -3.968,-0.16 -5.543,-2.009 -5.543,-2.009 l 3.57,-4.163 4.465,0.168 3.132,4.12 c 0,0 -2.89,1.994 -5.624,1.884 z" style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" /> <path d="m 18.453,33.843 c -0.849,-2.968 0.172,-6.884 0.172,-6.884 l 4,2.167 1.493,4.629 -3.582,4.233 c 0,-10e-4 -1.465,-1.99 -2.083,-4.145 z" style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" /> <path d="m 19.458,25.125 c 0,0 0.5,-1.958 3.039,-3.822 2.237,-1.643 4.465,-1.72 4.465,-1.72 l -0.037,4.981 -3.521,2.75 -3.946,-2.189 z" style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" /> <path d="M 32.084,27.834 28.625,24.959 29,19.75 c 0,0 1.834,-0.042 3.959,1.667 2.228,1.791 3.362,4.983 3.362,4.983 l -4.237,1.434 z" style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" /> <path d="m 31.292,34.042 1.313,-4.464 4.187,-1.536 c 0,0 0.677,2.663 -0.042,5.667 -0.54,2.256 -2.084,4.361 -2.084,4.361 l -3.374,-4.028 z" style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" /> </g> </svg>';

var PENPALETTEICON = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="55" height="55"> <path d="m 11.152285,41.709935 c 1.43401,0.788706 5.23977,1.402428 7.528553,1.290609 1.626167,-0.07945 3.914929,-0.479849 5.234137,-1.43401 2.238123,-1.618798 3.032695,-5.829627 5.090736,-7.671954 1.225701,-1.097229 3.231844,-2.444635 4.875634,-2.509518 2.003851,-0.07909 4.468168,1.514349 6.166244,2.581219 1.290216,0.810619 3.800127,3.369923 3.800127,3.369923" style="fill:none;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:2.5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1" /> <path d="m 35.566307,13.352385 2.437818,-2.366117 1.200984,0.84248 1.416085,1.200984 0.985882,1.272684 0.914181,1.487786 -2.366117,2.509519 -0.896257,-1.505711 -2.186866,-2.366117 -1.50571,-1.075508 z" style="fill:none;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:1px;stroke-opacity:1" /> <path d="m 32.877538,16.112854 2.294417,-2.079315 1.200984,0.84248 1.416085,1.200984 0.985882,1.272684 0.914181,1.487786 -2.079315,1.864214 -0.967957,-1.147208 -2.330267,-2.222716 -1.43401,-1.218909 z" style="fill:none;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:1px;stroke-opacity:1" /> <path d="m 13.423248,38.807621 0.891754,-3.80169 18.820708,-18.21056 -0.469344,-0.680549 2.252852,-2.135517 5.115854,5.115853 -2.229385,2.135517 -0.774419,-0.539747 -19.05538,18.022823 -3.70782,0.657082 -0.84482,-0.563212 z" style="fill:none;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:2.5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1" /> <path d="m 33.482432,17.358584 3.660886,3.473148" style="fill:none;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:2.5;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1" /> <path d="m 10.935723,41.905293 2.769132,-2.816066" style="fill:none;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:2.5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1" /> <path d="m 14.690478,35.287537 c 0,0 1.594197,0.393866 2.158983,0.93869 0.574138,0.553844 1.032558,2.158984 1.032558,2.158984" style="fill:none;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:2.5;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1" /> </svg>';

var NUMBERPALETTEICON = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="55" height="55"> <g transform="translate(6.1026134,-1.6740561)" style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1"> <text style="font-size:12px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:Bitstream Vera Sans"><tspan x="3.9423084" y="26.866751" id="tspan2386" style="font-size:18px;font-weight:normal;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;-inkscape-font-specification:AlArabiya">123</tspan></text> <text style="font-size:12px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:Bitstream Vera Sans"><tspan x="1.8153553" y="44.840736" style="font-size:18px;font-weight:normal;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;-inkscape-font-specification:AlArabiya">+–=</tspan></text> </g> </svg>';

var BOOLEANPALETTEICON = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="55" height="55" viewBox="0 0 55 55"><g style="fill:none;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:2.5;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none;display:block"><path d="m 10,25 c 0,-6 6,-12 12,-12 6,0 12,6 12,12 0,6 -6,12 -12,12 -6,0 -12,-6 -12,-12 m 11,0 c 0,-6 6,-12 12,-12 6,0 12,6 12,12 0,6 -6,12 -12,12 -6,0 -12,-6 -12,-12" style="fill:none;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:2.5;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none" /></g></svg>';


var PALETTEICONS = {
  'turtle': TURTLEPALETTEICON,
  'pen': PENPALETTEICON,
  'number': NUMBERPALETTEICON,
  'boolean': BOOLEANPALETTEICON
};

var output = document.getElementById('WebGL-output');
output.appendChild(webGLRenderer.domElement);

var x = 0;
var y = window.innerHeight / 2 - 27.5;
var buttons = {};

addIconOnScreen('pen');
addIconOnScreen('turtle');
addIconOnScreen('number');
addIconOnScreen('boolean');

function addIconOnScreen(name){
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    var texture = new THREE.Texture(img);
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: texture
    });
    material.transparent = true;
    material.depthWrite = false;

    var bitmap = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(img.width, img.height), material);
    bitmap.name = name;
    bitmap.position.setX(0);
    bitmap.position.setY(y);
    scene.add(bitmap);
    y-=55;

    webGLRenderer.render(scene, camera);        
};
img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(
unescape(encodeURIComponent(PALETTEICONS[name])));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r71/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="WebGL-output"></div>
```

I suspect that some kind of texture caching is taking place. When I load the new image I am overwriting the old texture cache. THREE.js is assuming that all the img I load are the same. Is there anyway to stop this texture cache?

EDIT : The other thing that I can think of is problem with closures. But I have gone through multiple times and it doesn't seem that way.

Comment: Can you provide a simple, live example to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: I still haven't been able to solve the problem, I have attached a fiddle that depicts the problem. Seems that it wasn't a closure related problem.

Comment: @WestLangley : I have removed the unnecessary portions of the earlier code, removed the loops as well, its just a single function now. Still the problem occurs, could you help me?

Comment: I am not sure what is going on... http://jsfiddle.net/1okpmzsw/ or http://jsfiddle.net/1okpmzsw/1/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When image loaded, you need use canvas:

```
img.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
    ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wzy7m85y/

Comment: This is a work-around, but the existing code works for the first texture, so it remains to understand what is going on... unless you know?

Comment: Three documentation doesn't refer to svg anywhere in the texture documentation so maybe that is the reason svg is causing problems. But thanks for this workaround for now.

Comment: I do not exactly understand the essence of this magic, but the problem is the implementation of the canvas `bindTexture` in different browsers: Firefox free in the same original sample works on hurray without overlapping. I have encountered a year ago with the same problem. http://jsfiddle.net/wzy7m85y/3/

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a browser bug, see: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=553885

It's fixed in Chrome 48.0.2557.0 canary (64-bit)