# SVG as texture gets blended in some way

Tags: svg, three.js

I've got a strange behaviour when using SVG as textures in three.js.

When loading the first texture all is fine but the second one contains the first one when used as a texture (they share the same viewBox in the SVG but that shouldn't be an issue normally). Stuff is working when using PNGs or other image files.

Here is a minimal example:
http://jsbin.com/xeyigahata/1/edit?html,js,output

Thx!

Comment: Interestingly this seems work fine without three.js and 2D canvas: http://jsbin.com/lesejevuqa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951739/texture-repeats-and-overlaps-in-three-js